# Volume estimation using multidate DEM

Tags: raster, dem, elevation

I have 10 multidate Cartosat-1 stereo pair derived raster DEMs of dates ranging over a decade over a river sand area. I want to derive volumes of sand deposited in that period within that area. Is it possible?

Comment: Are DEMs orthoregistered?

Comment: All the DEMs were generated in Leica Photogrammetry Suite using same set of GCPs taken from a single orthorectified image as reference. Also, I have generated respective orthorectified images from all the multidate DEMs. Those are coming perfectly coregistered.

Comment: If you are looking at changes in sediment within rivers, suggest you have a look at [this work](http://gcd.joewheaton.org/) first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your DEM is a raster, it's easy to derive its volume as

DEM_vol = sum(DEM * cell_size * cell_size)

The DEM_vol is meaningless but if you take the difference between successive years then you will get the volume difference you are looking for.  Just make sure your cell_size and elevation are in meters, in which case your result will be in cubic meters.